# Error trying to create table in MySQL via terminal

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, mysql2

I am trying to create a table in my database via terminal.

Here is my syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   PRIMARY KEY(id) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `last_name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   `first_name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   `gender`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   `fav_color`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   `birthdate`  DATE NOT NULL
);
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`last_name` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
`first_name` VARCHA' at line 2
```

What am i dong wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the issues that Jens and Marc pointed out, You have to declare the length of your Varchar fields in order for this statement to work, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `fav_color` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Answer (score 2):

the syntax of your create statement is wrong:

the correct one is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `gender`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `fav_color`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `birthdate`  DATE NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

For more Information see the [offical documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
id int primary key auto_increment not null
```

You're trying to define a primary key on a field that doesn't exist. Keys cannot be "not null" and definitely cannot be "auto_increment".

Comment: this is still giving me the same error, but referencing like 3 instead of line 2